# Regexp in Emacs progn

Tags: regex, emacs, auctex

I have the following Emacs macro, which evaluates the AucTex command `TeX-insert-macro` on selected text:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c (")
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (TeX-insert-macro "command")))))
```

However, how would I perform a regexp on the selected text and pass that to `TeX-insert-macro`?

[See this question for more details.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/command-emacs-selection-commandregexped-selection)

For example:
Suppose I have the following text:

> …as shown in figure (24).

Now, suppose I select "(24)." Then, I want a command to convert it to:

> …as shown in figure \command{eq:24}.

Viz., how would I define a new Emacs command that I could place in `~/.emacs` that would run `C-C RET command RET` on a regexp'ed version of the selected text?

**Why doesn't the following with regexp work?**

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c )")
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (query-replace-regexp "\(([0-9]+)\)" "\1")
     (TeX-insert-macro "eq")
))))
```

**Minor improvement:**

This works well if I select, e.g., "(45)" from the left to the right and then run the code by typing <kbd>C-c )</kbd>

```el
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c )")
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (exchange-point-and-mark)
     (replace-regexp "[\(\)]" "")
     (TeX-insert-macro "eq")
))))
```

However, if I select "(45)" from the right to the left, it doesn't work because the point and mark are flipped. Is there a way to make sure the point and mark aren't flipped, such as by running `exchange-point-and-mark` when they are flipped?

Also, there are other issue with the regexp, e.g., if there are other parentheses nearby it gets greedy.

thanks

Comment: The question is a bit confused. There are no macros here, other than (one presumes) `TeX-insert-macro`; and you cannot "perform" a regular expression.

Comment: @phils: What is the Lisp code above called, if not a macro?

Comment: @phils: I've edited the question with more detail.

Comment: There's no special name. It's just lisp code. A "macro" is lisp code which generates and evaluates more lisp code, and is defined with `defmacro` (or it can also refer to a "keyboard macro", which is a recorded sequence of keystrokes that can be played back as a single operation).

Comment: And in retrospect, the name `TeX-insert-macro` is referring to LaTeX macros, so that's undoubtedly just a plain function. You'll note that in all cases a "macro" is something which expands into something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the requisite libraries installed, or know how the TeX functions work, but something like this might do the trick.

```el
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (defun my-insert-latex-command-macro (beginning end)
       (interactive "r")
       (goto-char beginning)
       (when (not (looking-at "(\\(.+?\\))"))
         (error "Region does not match expected pattern."))
       (push-mark)
       (replace-match "eq:\\1")
       (exchange-point-and-mark)
       (TeX-insert-macro "command")
       (goto-char (mark))
       (pop-mark))
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c (") 'my-insert-latex-command-macro)))
```

Using the `"r"` argument for interactive conveniently gives you the region boundaries in ascending order, regardless of which direction you marked it in.

To avoid greedy matching in a regexp, use the non-greedy operators (`*?`, `+?`, `??`).

Note that you do not have sufficient backslash escapes in your regexps. In order to get a backslash into a regexp string in the first place, you first need to account for string escaping. Basically, double the backslashes. e.g.: This:

```
(query-replace-regexp "\(([0-9]+)\)" "\1")
```

needs to be this:

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\(([0-9]+)\\)" "\\1")
```

Comment: regexp is necessary to remove the parenthesis so "(46)" would go to "eq:46" which `TeX-insert-macro` would then take to produce `\eq{eq:46}`.

Comment: See the code above under the ***Why doesn't the following with regexp work?*** heading.

Comment: Ah, I missed the parenthesis part, and regexp replacement does seem reasonable in that case. Try the edited code.